# Свободное перемещение по картинке в вебе

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Хотелось бы узнать как можно сделать свободное перемещение по картинке на сайте. Что бы лапкой передвигаться по картинке. Желательно, что бы можно было разметить карту ссылок на картинке.

Comment: что значит "передвигатьcя"?

Comment: как в гугл картах или пдф документе приближенное изображение лапкой двигать)

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/  наверно это

Comment: @MaximLensky Да, оно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla.js + jQuery

> Смотреть на весь экран

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
  });
</script>
<script>
  var f = function() {
    function eventHandler(event) {
      var width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).width);
      var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).height);
      var zoom = 40;

      if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
        this.style.width = Math.min(2500, width + zoom) + "px";
        this.style.height = Math.min(2500, height + zoom) + "px";
      } else {
        this.style.width = Math.max(500, width - zoom) + "px";
        this.style.height = Math.max(500, height - zoom) + "px";
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    var imageElement = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    imageElement.addEventListener('mousewheel', eventHandler, false);
  };
  window.addEventListener('load', f, false);
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="item">
    <img id="draggable" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/484669973650874369/8FIN9ovT_400x400.jpeg" alt="" style="width:1000px; height:1000px; transform:translate(-100px,-100px);">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот вариант с `svg` + `d3.js`, здесь используется `d3.zoom()`, который по сути обрабатывает 2 типа событий `zoom` и `translate`

```js
var links = Array(100).fill(0).map(i => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)) 

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var image = svg.select("image").on('load', () => {
  let rect = image.node().getBoundingClientRect();
  svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .html(d => d)
    .attr("x", d => 50+Math.random()*(rect.width-100))
    .attr("y", d => 50+Math.random()*(rect.height-100))
    .on('click', function() {
      alert(d3.select(this).html());
    });
})

svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => {
  let t = d3.event.transform;
  image.attr("transform", t);
  svg.selectAll("text").attr("transform", t)
      .attr('font-size', 1/t.k*16);
}));

let resize = () => {
  svg.attr('width', window.innerWidth)
     .attr('height', window.innerHeight) 
};
resize();
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

text {
  fill: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  font-weight:bold;
}

text:hover {
  fill:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/RUJONAj.jpg"/>
</svg>
```

PS: без `d3` кода будет тоже весьма мало, но все же побольше =)

Comment: Как раз что то такое и нужно, спасибо большое!